# Persistent undo not working

Tags: undo-redo

I have the following in my .vimrc file:

```
if has('persistent_undo')
    " Save all undo files in a single location (less messy, more risky)...
    set undodir=$HOME/.VIM_UNDO_FILES

    " Save a lot of back-history...
    set undolevels=5000

    " Actually switch on persistent undo
    set undofile

endif
```

I've created the `.VIM_UNDO_FILES` in my home directory and have verified VIM has persistent_undo compiled in. Yet, when I close out a vim file and reopen, I cannot undo anything I did before the file was closed. Maybe I misunderstand how this is supposed to work.

I tried commenting out the if/endif and that didn't help. I also tried changing `$HOME` to `~`. that did not work either.

Also, the `.VIM_UNDO_FILES` file size never grows. It's stuck at 0.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm a dummy. I needed to create `.VIM_UNDO_FILES` as a dir not a file.